# Suggestions for new badges?

Tags: discussion

Would it be a good idea if users could propose new badges to apply specially to ELUSE? For example, they could go on to Stack Exchange network, and propose to the top users(people with over 10000 rep?) a badge that could be instituted. Of course it is possible that this is misused and silly badges are proposed and accepted. The top users will have to hold the responsibility to vote wisely and preserve the SE reputation. Would this be a good idea, or is this just too much?

Answer (score 5):

I appreciate the sentiment, but it is very unlikely we will pursue site-specific badges at this time; we'd rather build features that help all sites on the network, at least a little.

(there are of course exceptions like the MathJax support for math, stats, quant, cstheory, etc)

Comment: speaking of exceptions such as MathJax support, how about helping us with a [font that support the International Pronunciation Alphabet](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1027). That would really make English.SE better (as well as the upcoming Linguistics proposal, and other language sites).